# Remove a row in a dataframe with empty series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a data frame. That has an empty series in its row:

```
0                                          4.5
1                                          0.5
2                                            8
3                                            8
4                                            8
                        ...                   
704                                        3.5
705                                        0.5
706                                       11.5
707                                        0.5
708    Series([], Name: price, dtype: float64)
Name: pricediff, Length: 709, dtype: object",
0                                           4
1                                         0.5
2                                         2.5
3                                        19.5
4                                        19.5
                       ...                   
58                                          1
59                                          4
60                                        8.5
61    Series([], Name: price, dtype: float64)
62    Series([], Name: price, dtype: float64)
Name: pricediff, Length: 63, dtype: object",
```

How can I remove the row or replace it with 0, without directly doing df.drop(df.index[61]), etc, because I have multiple data

Comment: Can you clarify that example data? It's difficult to tell what is what. Why do you even have Series alongside floats in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if each element is an empty series and then replace all those entries.

First, we'll create a test DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (3, 3)))
df[3] = [1, pd.Series([]), 5]
```

So, we have:

```
    0   1   2                           3
0  31  29   1                           1
1  86  86  71  Series([], dtype: float64)
2  86  80  21                           5
```

Now, we introduce a function to make empty Series to 0 and apply it to our DataFrame.

```
def make_empty_series_zero(element):
    if isinstance(element, pd.Series) and len(element) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return element


df.applymap(make_empty_series_nan)
```

After applying it to our DataFrame, we have:

```
    0   1   2  3
0  57  58   2  1
1  96  27   8  0
2   0  43  91  5
```